# I use Fresco in my Android Project, but it lacks of attributes such as 'roundAsCircle'

Tags: android, xml, facebook, android-studio, fresco

I've added this to my build gradle:

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.1'
```

and this in my layout xml:

```
xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

but in fresco namespace,it only has 4 attributes:`fresco:actualImageUri=""`
, `fresco:paddingEnd=""`, `fresco:paddingStart=""`, `fresco:theme=""`

and I can't find `fresco:placeHolderImage=""` and `fresco:roundAsCircle=""`,which are what I actually need.I try to add these attributes in my xml,but when I make the project,the IDE shows the error that 'No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundAsCirle' in package ....'

**I've tried these:**

- clean my project and restart Android Studio after adding `compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.1'`  to build.gradle and `xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to layout xml.
- use different version of fresco,such as 0.12.0.But the same problem occurred
- I've encountered this problem in at least two project,but in previous project it just disappeared and I have no idea how.
- I've searched Google and the website of fresco,but no related imformation found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same library version for one of my project; have you properly initialized the library in your Application class?

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
        Fresco.initialize(this);
}
```

Comment: @ZionQ Try to invalidate the cache on Android Studio: **File|Invalidate Caches/Restart**